# Hive - Combining multiple table generating functions

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to combine the following hive queries

**Query 1**

 SELECT adid FROM galdata WHERE galdata.email IN (SELECT explode(split(recipients,'[|]')) AS sub FROM inbound_mails where msguid='xxx')

**Query 1 Result**

user1,user2

**Query 2**

SELECT msgsize_kb, userid FROM inbound_mails LATERAL VIEW explode(**split('user1,user2','[,]')**) 
subView AS userid where msguid='xxx'

**Query 2 Result**

670847,user1

670847,user2

Note that I have deliberately hard coded the result of Query 1 in an array format inside Query 2 to demonstrate the result that I require.

The problem is how do I use Query1 inside Query2 to get the result.  When I tried combining like this:

 
 *SELECT msgsize_kb, userid FROM inbound_mails LATERAL VIEW explode(SELECT adid FROM galdata WHERE galdata.email IN (SELECT explode(split(recipients,'[|]')) AS sub FROM inbound_mails where msguid='xxx')) subView AS userid where msguid='xxx'*

It gave me the following error

Error occurred executing hive query: OK FAILED: ParseException line 6:81 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'adid' 'FROM' in function specification

Can any one please help

Comment: @What is the Hive version, is this lesser then CDH4

Comment: Hive Version is 0.13.0

Comment: You selected one column, `adid`,  in query1 and your query returned two columns.  How is this possible?

Comment: Sorry it is not 2 columns, but 2 rows.  The explode function will generate a row containing adid for each recipient